# Why " other" not " others"

Tags: word-usage, morphology

I saw this sentence in the Cambridge Dictionary.

> We'll find someone or ***other*** to help us.

Why does this sentence use " other" rather than " others" or " other people" ?

Comment: *Something/someone/somewhere or other* is an idiom, a fixed phrase that we use: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/something%20or%20other

Answer (score 3):

"Someone" is singular (some **one**) therefore the alternative, "other", should also be singular.

Comment: See examples  of **or other** usage at: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/something-someone-somewhere-etc-or-other